# No puedo leer ni guardar archivo json

Tags: python, json

Tengo este programa que ya esta todo hecho, pero mi problema es que no me lee ni guarda el archivo json. Cuando lo ejecuto con el programa principal no me aparece el archivo json. ¿Como puedo hacer para arreglar ese problema?

```py
import json

from datetime import datetime as dt

def leer_archivo():
    cadena = ''
    with open('mascotas.json', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as archivo:
        cadena = archivo.read()
    return json.loads(cadena)

def guardar_archivo(lista):
    cadena = json.dumps(lista)
    with open('mascotas.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as archivo:
        archivo.write(cadena)

def filtrar_por_especie(lista, especie):
    res = []
    for elem in lista:
        if elem ["especie"] == especie:
            res.append(elem)
    return res

def filtrar_mayores(lista):
    res = []
    hoy = dt.now()
    for elem in lista:
        nacimiento = dt.strftime(elem["nacimiento"], '%d/%m/%Y')
        if (hoy - nacimiento).days/365 >= 10:
            res.append(elem)
    return res

def orden_nombre(x):
    return x["Nombre"]

def ordenar_por_nombre(lista):
    lista.sort(key=orden_nombre)
    return lista

def max_numero(x):
    return x["nro_paciente"]

def proximo_numero(lista):
     return 1 + max(lista, key=max_numero) ["nro_paciente"]
```

Comment: Pues tienes una colección de funciones que no llamas de ningún lado. Si quieres que se lea el archivo, tienes que ejecutar `contenido = leer_archivo()`

Comment: "Con el programa principal" <-- cuál es el programa principal???